# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find' in python, collatz conjecture

Tags: python, python-3.x, collatz

i tried to create a python program that automates the collatz conjecture, i want it to print every number that it is working on, the number of numbers that it had worked and state(pending, pending successful and successful)but when i ran it ,it has an error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

here is the code:

```
import random

x = None
y = None
nru = None
nra = None
history = None
z = None
s = None
text1 = None
text2 = None
inpt = None

# Describe this function...
def func1():
  global x, y, nru, nra, history, z, s, text1, text2
  x = random.randint(1, 100)
  nru = x
  z = 2
  func4()

# Describe this function...
def func2():
  global x, y, nru, nra, history, z, s, text1, text2
  if x % 2 == 0:
    x = x / 2
  else:
    x = x * 3 + 1
  func3()

# Describe this function...
def func3():
  global x, y, nru, nra, history, z, s, text1, text2
  if x == 1:
    nra = nra + 1
    func1()
  else:
    if not history.find(y)+ 1 == 0:
      z = 3
      s = 'pending successful'
      func4()
    else:
      z = 1
      func4()

# Describe this function...
def func4():
  global x, y, nru, nra, history, z, s, text1, text2
  if z == 1:
    history = ''.join([str(x2) for x2 in [history, "'", x, "'"]])
    func2()
  elif z == 2:
    print(''.join([str(x3) for x3 in [text1, nru, text2, nra, s]]))
    func2()
  elif z == 3:
    nra = nra + 1
    print(''.join([str(x4) for x4 in [text1, nru, text2, nra, s]]))
    func5()


# Describe this function...
def func5():
  global x, y, nru, nra, history, z, s, text1, text2
  print(history)
  inpt = input("flaw? y/n")
  if inpt == 'y':
    s = 'pending'
    nra = nra + 1
    func1()
  elif inpt == 'n':
    s = 'success'


x = 0
y = 0
z = 0
s = 'pending'
nra = 0
nru = 0
text1 = 'The number that is running'
text2 = 'Number of numbers that ran'
text2 = 0
inpt = '0'
func1()
```

and also the answer isn't satisfying:

```
The number that is running9900pending
```

I want it to be multiline but not just single lined
can any one help me please and give me some suggestions?
(i knew the range of numbers are small but it's just a test)

Comment: Stop using global variables. Return values from functions and pass them a long to other functions

Comment: Any way, `history` is never being set to something other than `None` before calling `history.find`